# using ViewBag as an object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

If I have multiple ViewBag lines inside controller

```
ViewBag.ShowElement1 = myObj.IsAllowed;
ViewBag.PageLabel = someotherObj.PersonName;
....
```

which I of course use inside view to access some value I wonder if there any better solution to wrap this into 1 logic piece so I can access inside view like

```
ViewBag.MyRestricts.ShowElement1
ViewBag.MyRestricts.ShowElement8
```

Comment: Create a class and use that? I get the feeling that you may be abusing the ViewBag somewhat though.

Comment: it's not a good practice? Just asking

Comment: It looks like you are trying to pass a bunch of data to your view, can't you just use the view model?

Comment: Using `ViewBag` is an anti-pattern. It's handy for certain things like passing a title into your layout, but it's extremely easy to abuse and boy is it *abused*. Long and short, avoid it like the plague. Minimal use is fine (such as the page title scenario), but anything more than that should be handled by a true model.

Comment: @user1765862 I wrote an article why you should avoid `ViewBag` with some examples. This should give you an idea why it is bad: https://jamietech.com/2015/10/14/mvc-view-models-or-viewdata/

Answer (score 3):

Best Solution will be if you will create a **ViewModel** and add anything that your **View** need to it.And then create **Strong-Typed View with model of your ViewModel.**

**One View - One ViewModel**.Anything your View needs it must be in the ViewModel

There are some rules.

**Rule #1 – All Views are strongly-typed
 Rule #2 – For each ViewModel type, there is defined exactly one strongly typed
          View
 Rule #3 – The View dictates the design of the ViewModel.  Only what is required

          to render a View is passed in with the ViewModel.
 Rule #4 – The ViewModel contains only data and behavior related to the View**

[image]

This is a good post.I think it will be interestring for you
https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a ViewModel instead? You can define a class with properties such as ShowElement1 and PageLabel and then access this in the view by adding this line at the top:

```
@model TheTypeOfYourClass
```

Then you can just use `@Model.PageLabel` to access the property.

Answer (score 0):

As was said before the best solution here is to use ViewModel, because using heavy viewbags considered as bad practice. You can read about this [here](http://tech.trailmax.info/2013/12/asp-net-mvc-viewbag-is-bad/) and I totally agree with this post :

Here is how Viewmodel will look like:

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public bool ShowElement1 { get; set; }
        public string PageLabel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            ShowElement1 = myObj.IsAllowed,
            PageLabel = someotherObj.PersonName
        };

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

And your view will be something like this:

```
@model MyProject.Models.MyViewModel

<p>ShowElement1 value: @Model.ShowElement1</p> 
<p>PageLabel value: @Model.PageLabel </p>
```

Comment: I doubt that will would be a better solution since the model most likely is already used and the viewbag contains view related data.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an anonymouse object

```
ViewBag.MyRestricts = new { ShowElement1 = true, ShowElement2 = false, };
```

or you could create a class for that

```
public class Restricts
{
    public bool ShowElement1 { get; set; }
    public bool ShowElement8 { get; set; }
} 
ViewBag.MyRestricts = new Restricts { ShowElement1 = true, ShowElement2 = false, };
```

and in your view

```
var restricts = (Restricts)ViewBag.MyRestricts;
if (restricts.ShowElement1)
    ....
```